# Overstriken and Ignored PyDev BreakPoints

Tags: eclipse, pydev, breakpoints, eclipse-juno, eclipse-kepler

Suddenly breakpoints have stopped working in Eclipse PyDev. When I double click on the left margin in the code editor everything seems to work fine except that a blue diagonal overstrike appears on top of the break point symbol in the margin. Note that the overstrike is diagonal so it has nothing todo with the breakpoint being disabled. When I disable it I get yet another horizontal overstrike as usual. But when I run the code (with breakspoints enable) the debugger ignores all breakpoint still. The problem occurs on both Juno and Kepler. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagonal overstrike means that you have the 'Skip All Breakpoints' toggle set in the Breakpoints view.